# What about making questions/discussions reach more audience via existing social networks?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

So what about idea of making it connected to some of existing social networks with more ease.  I find these reasons for it...

- It will extend the reach to get it noticed by many others including some other fellow coders in ones friend list.
- It will be helpful for initiatives like code.org, making public more curious about learning to code.
- It will, to a great extent, increase the traffic on Stack Overflow, further increasing the revenue(if it's a subject of matter with an importance to a company, be it no-profit company)
- It will attract Coding Buds, i.e. Teenage and below Teenage folks(using Facebook for the sake of jus!) to see something of useful to see in their news feeds than some other crap things happenings all around(subjective clause).

Comment: My god, NOoooooo...

Answer (score 9):

**Note:** This response is to the request to *encourage* putting more content on social media via a prominent "share" button or any sort of automation. Obviously we already have the "Share" link on every post, and thats fine by me.

First off, SE/SO is **not** a social platform for programmers. Its a Q & A repository. The goals are very different.

I see this feature as driving a lot of *unwanted* traffic. To your points:

> It will extend the reach to get it noticed by many others including
>   some other fellow coders in ones friendlist.

Most experienced programmers know about Stack Overflow. This might reach some new people, but I don't see a lot of benefit here.

> It will be helpful for initiatives like code.org, making public more
>   curious about learning to code.

SO isn't here to teach people to code. I'm all for people learning, but we don't need more "Give me teh codez" or "How to learn X language" questions

> It will, to a great extent, increase the traffic on StackOverflow,
>   further increasing the revenue(if it's a subject of matter with an
>   importance to a company, be it no-profit company)

Ok, this might happen. I don't think lack of traffic is really SO's problem though.

> It will attract Coding Buds, i.e. Teenage and below Teenage
>   folks(using fb for the sake of jus!) to see something of useful to see
>   in their news feeds than some other crap things happenings all
>   around(subjective clause).

See my point about us not being here to teach people to code. The effect could also work in reverse, if such people see truly *good* content, its likely to be so far over their heads that it could turn them off. At the very least, they are unlikely to understand it.

Comment: Agree with you to much extent. Still I can see a bit of positives indeed through so much negatives you highlighted :-)

Comment: @Sachin Sure, there are potential positives. I just see the negatives *far* outweighing them.

Comment: It's ok. I just threw my idea which'd been revolving in my mind. Agree with you to much extent.

Answer (score 6):

This already exists:

> [image]

Comment: Huh. My mistake. Couldn't notice ever! Apologies...