# What main features would a social network like Stack Overflow have and how would they make the platform a social network?

Tags: discussion, scope, user-experience, community

> Wikipedia, the world’s largest online encyclopedia, boasts an ambitious vision: to make “the sum of all human knowledge” freely available on the internet. Its strategy for doing so? Turn everyday web users into unpaid, online “editors”. [Guardian article Nov 2019](https://www.theguardian.com/careers/2019/nov/28/making-the-edit-why-we-need-more-women-in-wikipedia)

Does that sound familiar? Wikipedia as well as Stack Overflow both represent a collaborative effort of volunteers to create some sort of knowledge repository. In that regard both seem to have much in common and they were both quite successful so far.

I just read this article linked above. One concern mentioned in it is the current low contribution rate of women (to the extent that it can be estimated) to Wikipedia. A way to counteract it according to the article is promotion as well as adapting the interface of Wikipedia to include more social elements, allow to form personal bonds, and have social interactions within the community.

This is just for motivation. I know that Stack Overflow is generally regarded as not a very social network (see for example [Should we be able to send private messages to other users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/should-we-be-able-to-send-private-messages-to-other-users), [Can we add a user to user chat function on Stack overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336705/can-we-add-a-user-to-user-chat-function-on-stack-overflow-what-could-be-advanta?noredirect=1&lq=1), [How to find out if a particular user is online or offline on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343602/how-to-find-out-if-a-particular-user-is-online-or-offline-on-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1)), although lately with all the personal answers to the moderator resignation notices or the goodbye threads to former CMs, I would say that indeed users of Stack Overflow form social bonds through their contributions on the platform (platform includes Stack Overflow main as well as meta). [The personal connection is something that grows as you get deeper and deeper into the community.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392922/1536976).

In  order to get an impression of how a social Stack Overflow platform (a main and a meta site) would actually look like:

If Stack Overflow (main and meta) would be a social network similar to the big known social networks (Facebook, Instagram, ...) but specialized on programming related questions with the aim of constructing a Q&A knowledge base and also teach people with a certain level skill set how to improve their skills, how would it look like most likely? What would be the major features? Which features would likely be additionally present to the ones that are already there? How would they work to make the place a social network? I'm mostly interested in getting a good collection of possible elements, so there is not inherent right or wrong.

It seems as if this has not yet been discussed as such. Searching for "social", "social network", "community" brought only topics like [What about making questions/discussions reach more audience via existing social networks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283283/what-about-making-questions-discussions-reach-more-audience-via-existing-social) or [Is it against the rules to solicit upvotes on third-party websites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331659/is-it-against-the-rules-to-solicit-upvotes-on-third-party-websites), [Which of my LinkedIn and Facebook connections are on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326277/which-of-my-linkedin-and-facebook-connections-are-on-stack-overflow), which are more about interactions with existing social networks.

Please note that I don't want to discuss what the disadvantages and advantages of Stack Overflow as a social network would be, I want to know how it would like look if it was one and what features it would have, regardless of how useful they would be or not.

Comment: related? ["scaling by breaking the social network..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/839601)

Comment: You seems to be conflating Meta Stack Overflow (moderator resignation notices, goodbye threads to former CMs) with Stack Overflow (programming related questions). It would be good to be explicit in where the social aspects are to be introduced in this thought experiment.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow are both part of the whole platform. In this question I explicitly want to include Stack Overflow the main site. Will edit it to emphasize this more.

Comment: FWIW I don't think it would be feasible for Stack Overflow (Main) and still be a Q&A site. For Meta, maybe... Personally, I also do not *want* indiscriminate "social" connection with the "unwashed millions". From experience, most are interested in getting free help. Any social/community relations would be with those with similar interests on the site, which means Meta. And the other parts of my life probably wouldn't interest most people here :-) For the few cases they would, there's chat.

Comment: @CindyMeister There are quite a number of successful social networks out there, it's not immediately clear to me why one focused on programming Q&A should not work. In this question, I want to concentrate more on how that would look like and less if it would work.

Comment: But if it wouldn't work, then how it might look is immaterial? It doesn't matter how many there are already and whether or not they're successful - that has no bearing on a site/concept that was not designed for the purpose.

Comment: @CindyMeister But we don't know if it would or wouldn't work. As a frame challenge that should be valid in an answer though, I think. It's not really obvious to me why it wouldn't work and I would not assume that.

Comment: _"Please note that I don't want to discuss what the disadvantages and advantages of Stack Overflow as a social network would be"_ Then what's the point of this question? __"What-ifs"__ and the like aren't useful, especially if we're forbidden from discussing the __"why (not)"__. This seems to be discussion for the sake of discussion, which ironically is a better fit for a actual social network.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can only discuss the why (not) if you know the subject. It seems everyone has an implicit idea of what Stack Overflow as a social network would look like, but nobody is able to write it down. Social networks may not be really well defined, but they should share enough characteristics to make some educated guess. If you think that it's impossible that's fine as a frame challenge, but otherwise I would prefer to have a model of what SO as social network would be before comparing the pros and cons of it. Not a discussion for the sake of discussion but for enabling further discussion.

Comment: @CindyMeister I found a social network that's somewhat similar, but of course not really identical: ResearchGate. It has networks of profiles but questions and answers as well.

Comment: _Social Interaction (SI):_ Personal messaging system. Con: People would get bothered about questions. _SI:_ Personal questions on meta. Con: Your kid starts walking? We don't care. SI: Extensive user profiles. Con: people start voting based on looks, ethnicity, gender, sexuality, whatever.  Every single "Social" feature or functionality you can think of has plenty of reasons why they would be a bad for for a ___Q&A___ site. They're different things at their core. There's no point in discussing how it would work, because it wouldn't. It's not what people visit SO for.

Comment: @Cerbrus I disagree somewhat and think you may be a bit too confident at some places. There might not be a point for you, which is totally fine, but there may be a point for me.

Comment: This would fundamentally damage a system which is built to be content oriented. I don't think we need more social network features at Stack Overflow. If anything, we need less.

Comment: Repository of knowledge <> Social platform. Turning any repository of knowledge into social platform (or just adding more "social platform" appeal) will be detrimental to core goal of creating repository of knowledge.

Comment: Tried to make the question less opinionated by emphasizing that there is no strict right or wrong and the aim is to get a collection of features and how they likely look like if you compare with existing big social networks. That should make the question answerable and anyway every discussion includes opinions to some extent.

Comment: @TravisJ "I don't think we need more social network features at Stack Overflow." That's fine. I'm more interested in knowing what this social network features would be that we don't need. What do we not need?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "Turning any repository of knowledge into social platform..." But isn't it already a social platform to some extent? People engage with each other, there are profiles, the content is produced by the users, there is even a community of some sort. That are all characteristics of social platforms.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia-like aspect of SO is somewhat gone by now. It's slowly turning into a personalised solve-my-problem site anyway. What's necessary is a clear direction. Is SO "saturated", and the only sensible new content is personalised help, so turning it into a one-on-one social model makes sense? Then we can think about what that might look like. Or should we try to "turn back the tide" and re-focus on the Wikipedia goal? Or perhaps both, with some sort of spinoff or mix?

Comment: @deceze Even for Wikipedia, which has the knowledge base goal, they think about adding more social elements, so maybe it's not detrimental if done right. But what is wrong with first looking what it would look like and then deciding if it makes sense? What is a one-on-one social model? Maybe classes and tutors? Graduate of the Stack Overflow Java beginners class of 2020.

Comment: I read the entire post hoping there would be a punchline somewhere.

Comment: @Matthew The punchline is the score. ;) Thanks for reading.

Comment: @deceze Even if it goes into "personal help desk" direction, that would not be enough to call SO social network, nor would adding social networking features add value to such SO.

Comment: @Trilarion - The features we need less of here are already incorporated through third party anyway. The system was not designed to support user coordination outside of the Q&A format.

Answer (score 12):

Stack exchange isn't, and shouldn't be a "Social Network".

- Social Feature (SF): Personal messaging system.
  Con: People would get bothered about questions.
- SF: Blog posts / personal questions on SO.
  Con: Your kid starts walking? We don't care. It's also not relevant to quality Q&A.  (**NR2QA**)
- SF: Extensive user profiles.
  Con: people start voting based on looks, ethnicity, gender, sexuality, whatever.  **NR2QA**
- SF: Links between user profiles.
  Con: people will harass you for a bad question a friend posted. **NR2QA**
- SF: A personal information feed.
  Con: Facebook has done it. Stack Overflow isn't Facebook, and shouldn't be. **NR2QA**

Every single "Social" feature or functionality you can think of has plenty of reasons why they would be a bad for for a Q&A site. They're different things at their core. There's no point in discussing how it would work, because it wouldn't. It's not what people visit SO for.

You're comparing Stack Overflow with social networks, while that is ***exactly*** what SO *isn't* meant to be.

Answer (score -10):

I don't feel like an expert about social networks and have most of my knowledge about social networks from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_networking_service) and from own experience only, but I will try my best to give an answer that includes which common features of social networks are already present and which are not and how they could look like. Social networks are themselves somewhat heterogeneous and there is no clear-cut set of features, so I just take all that I can find.

What is already there:

- Stack Overflow is an interactive website with user generated content. The user generated content is restricted mostly to programming in form of questions and answers though.
- The revenue of the platform is created from the engagement between users, here indirectly by creating the content during the engagement but collecting the ad revenue later when visitors from search engines find the content.
- There are personal profiles depicting the activity of each user.
- There is tagging, there is commenting. Again tagging and commenting is mostly restricted to programming, with comments that are not longer necessary getting deleted.
- There is some sense of community. People use Meta to discuss site-wide issues.

Features that are not present on Stack Overflow but typically found on social networks include:

- Diary-style web logs, i.e. information about the daily activity of users. These could be text or video blogs. On Stack Overflow this would probably be mostly focused on daily programming activity. Chat could be a place where such information is exchanged, but the style of chat is not diary-style.
- Links between profiles of users, i.e. some kind of friends or followers functionality.
- Personal (private) messages between users, mostly between users and followers.
- A feed that highlights personal information from followed users by some kind of selection algorithm.
- Apparently, they need a purpose. They must be good for something. Stack Overflow's purpose is creating a knowledge base but also answering specific programming questions and therefore also learning. A social network like Stack Overflow could emphasize this learning aspect, for example by something like tutoring. Not sure how that would look like though.

Somewhat similar existing cases:

ResearchGate or Academia.edu: they are science related social networks, allowing scientists to connect with others by maintaining a publication list and some sort of CV but also the ability to ask questions and get them answered or take part in discussions.
If one would replace science with programming, the publication list with tag badges and the CV with the developer story this could be somewhat similar to Stack Overflow as a social network. It could have two pillars, one concentrated on Q&A and the other on developer stories and connecting with others on a professional level.

Summary

I think that the main features that social networks have and Stack Overflow hasn't would be more extensive personal relationships, i.e. the ability to mark others as connected and to somehow get a compiled activity feed from them and to be able to communicate with them. Many other features of social networks are already present and after writing this answer I'm not sure anymore that Stack Overflow isn't already some kind of social network. I'm surprised, but it seems it's really only that (personal relations) mostly.

While it seems that only the personal relationships are missing mostly, they are also the most important part of a social network. For social networks it's main purpose is about maintaining a web of personal relations while Stack Overflow so far was mostly concerned with building up knowledge. And from the comments to this question it becomes clear that many people are convinced that personal relations and building up knowledge bases via Q&A are detrimental.

Comment: *"The revenue of the platform is created from the engagement between users"* — I don't think that's true. Most revenue comes from ad revenue which is mostly generated by anonymous visitors coming from Google, with other revenue generated by Jobs and auxiliary services, which are mostly advertised through the presence of SO on Google search results. "Interaction" only generates revenue indirectly insofar as it generates valuable content. The "interaction" part of it is not really relevant though. It's not like Facebook which you visit because you want to interact with others.

Comment: Overall, I'm not sure what the purpose of this would be. I'm not here to engage with my "favourite programmers" or something. It's the questions which are fun to answer. I couldn't care less *who* wrote them, I would not want to "follow" anyone personally. If anything, I'm following *technologies*, which is what SO already does.

Comment: @deceze I clarified that the revenue is only indirectly based on the engagement of users. I tend to agree with seeing personal relationships with other programmers here as not very helpful, but mostly because there are other social networks like LinkedIn for example that already do it and would probably do it so much better.